# Sending data from static cells in tableview in container view to view controller in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

swift noob here...

I have a view controller with a container view to a tableview controller because I want to use static cells. I have a label in the view controller that I want to be updated by a textfield in the static cell of the container tableview. Here's what I got, but the label isn't updating.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "tvEmbed") {

        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController

        self.textField.text = newViewController.label.text


    }
```

I know I don't have to use static cells for this purpose but this is just for me to get an idea of how it will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `textField`'s `text` to the value from `newViewController`, not the other way around.  Change your assignment to:

```
newViewController.label.text = self.textField.text
```

Comment: Duh... stupid me. How do I update the label to reflect the change in the textfield?